# GAEでの自作REST APIにAPIキーにて制限をかける方法

Tags: google-app-engine

GAEで作成した自作のREST APIへのアクセスを、他のGoogleAppsAPIが行っているように
APIキーを使用して署名付きのAndroid端末からのみのアクセスのみ許可するように制限をかけたいのですが、
それらしきIFがGAE/Goのドキュメントに見当たりません。

APIキーの作成方法自体はGCPコンソールのAPIManager＞認証情報から作成したのですが、
GAEで組んだ自作REST APIにそれを適用するにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gae自身にAPI Keyを付与することはできません。(現状)
そのような場合CloudEndpointとしてAPIを作成し、認証情報を付加する必要があります。
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/